# I am wondering what"the simple cast off items" means

Tags: meaning, construction

Take metal cans, for instance, and imagine them in any number of uses, functional or purely as an art form. Can your eyes and mind see the potential metal case, bird feeder, or other object in **the simple cast off items**? What about boxes or clothing? What might be done with these? Boxes can usually serve as new storage containers, and almost, always serve as very imaginative forts for the kids, not to mention makeshift shelters for pets. And clothing?

I neither see what the bold part means nor analyse it.

Comment: [hyphens matter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cast-off)

Comment: Also, don't forget that the past participle form of *cast* is *cast* not *casted*.

Comment: @Kreiri: Unfortunately the [source](https://books.google.de/books?id=BS8WBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&dq=Take+metal+cans,+for+instance,+and+imagine&hl=de&sa=X&ei=h4tkVamiOdCO7AbsnYPwAg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Take%20metal%20cans%2C%20for%20instance%2C%20and%20imagine&f=false) doesn't care about hyphens...

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not correct, "Cast off" should be either "cast-off" or "castoff". Each is an adjective meaning "discarded", although "castoff", particularly the plural "castoffs" is also a noun meaning a discarded item or items. As an adjective, cast-off is more common than castoff, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=castoff%2C+cast-off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccastoff%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccast%20-%20off%3B%2Cc0
[image]

The phrase "cast off" is a verb phrase, which can mean either to discard or to throw overboard (specifically applied to ship's lines when undocking).

Answer (score 1):

> Can your eyes and mind see the potential metal case, bird feeder, or other object in **the simple cast off items**?

**Cast off** is a phrase that means **discarded** and functions as an adjective.  A bit more punctuation might then make the troublesome phrase more clear:

> [...] in **the simple, cast off items**

It's two adjectives (**simple** and **cast off**) modifying **items**.

So the sentence can be rendered with that substitution:

> Can your eyes and mind see the potential metal case, bird feeder, or other object in the simple, discarded items?

I think part of your problem may not actually be in the part you indicated, but rather in the expression **see the [X] in the [Y]**.

That formula means to realize some non-obvious property, X, that the thing, Y, has.  So one might say:

> I try to see the beauty in the rain.

To express the idea that though rain may seem gloomy or ugly, one tries to realize that conceived of, or perceived, a certain way, rain can be beautiful.

Likewise, one might say:

> The sculptor sees the sculpture in the block of marble.

To express that the sculptor can envision in the block of marble, which looks like an inert, uninteresting rock, a dynamic, compelling work of art that could be made from it.  This is very similar to the sentiment of your example sentence:

> Can your eyes and mind see the potential metal case, bird feeder, or other object **in** the simple cast off items?

That **in** in there means that the reader is being asked if they can envision how a metal case, a bird feeder, or other (implied: *useful*) object could be made from simple items that were discarded (implied: *useless*).